# Find Id and insert a BsonArray into collection MongoDB

Tags: c#, mongodb, winforms

I have this collection

```
    db.UserWatchtbl.insert( { 
fbId: "", 
Name: "user3", 
pass: "pass3",
Watchtbl: 
    [ 
        { 
        wid: "1350",
        name: "bought stock1",
        Symboles: [ { Name: "AAA" }, { Name: "BSI" } ] 
        },
        { 
        wid: "1350",
        name: "bought stock2",
        Symboles: [ { Name: "AAA" }, { Name: "BSI" }, { Name: "EXXI" } ] 
        },
        { 
        wid: "1350",
        name: "bought stock2",
        Symboles: [ { Name: "AAA" }, { Name: "BSI" }, { Name: "EXXI" } ] 
        }
    ]
} )
```

My form is loading the Id list from the MongoDB then I select the ID that I want to insert the new  WatchTbl with the data.
And I try to find an Id then I insert into **Watchtbl** their Data.

```
private async void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // add user into datagridview from MongoDB Colelction Watchtbl
        var client = new MongoClient("mongodb://dataservername:27017");

        var database = client.GetDatabase("WatchTblDB");
        var collectionWatchtbl = database.GetCollection<BsonDocument>("UserWatchtbl");

        var document = new BsonDocument();
        BsonArray arrSym = new BsonArray();
        BsonArray arrWatc = new BsonArray();

        document.Add("wid", WIDTextBox.Text.ToString());
        document.Add("name", NameComboBox.SelectedItem.ToString());

        foreach (var item in SymbolesListBox.SelectedItems)
        {
            arrSym.Add(new BsonDocument("Name", item.ToString()));
        }
        document.Add("Symboles", arrSym);

        arrWatc.Add(new BsonDocument("Watchtbl", document));



        var result = await collectionWatchtbl.FindOneAndUpdateAsync(
                            Builders<BsonDocument>.Filter.Eq("_id", UsersComboBox.SelectedItem.ToString()),
                            Builders<BsonDocument>.Update.Set("Watchtbl", arrWatc)
                            );
    }
```

Bu It looks my code not working, So any help with that?

**Update** 
After Add the code of **ntohl**
I face this problem when I try to insert into collection
[image]

Comment: If I understand correctly, the result would look like "{ ... Watchtbl: [{...}, {...}, {...}, <new document here with `WIDTextBox.Text.ToString()` wid, `NameComboBox.SelectedItem.ToString()` name, etc.> ] } ". If that is the case, than the UserWatchtbl changes size, which is [not possible](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/capped-collections/) in a capped collection. Please recreate the collection, with db.createCollection( "UserWatchtbl", { capped: false })

Comment: yes, that's it, I test with another  collection not capped, and it works :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have a little advantage here, because I have answered Your previous post, and I could use it as a base. I have added the collection initialization part also, because the type of the elements are important. You need to have `SymboleCls` in the `SymbolesListBox.ItemsSource` to have it work for example. And UsersComboBox must have `ObjectId`s. You don't have to create the whole array, or You need to fill it with previous elements, if You use `Update.Set`. Instead I used `AddToSet`.

```
private readonly IMongoCollection<BsonDocument> collectionWatchtbl;

public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    var client = new MongoClient("mongodb://localhost:27017");

    var database = client.GetDatabase("test");
    collectionWatchtbl = database.GetCollection<BsonDocument>("UserWatchtbl");

    var filter = new BsonDocument();
    var user = new List<UserWatchTblCls>();
    var cursor = collectionWatchtbl.FindAsync(filter).Result;
    cursor.ForEachAsync(batch =>
    {
        user.Add(BsonSerializer.Deserialize<UserWatchTblCls>(batch));
    });

    UsersComboBox.ItemsSource = user.Select(x => x.Id);
    SymbolesListBox.DisplayMember = "Name";
    SymbolesListBox.ItemsSource =
        user.SelectMany(x => x.WatchTbls).SelectMany(y => y.Symbols);
}

private void ButtonBase_OnClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var document = new BsonDocument();
    BsonArray arrSym = new BsonArray();
    //BsonArray arrWatc = new BsonArray();

    document.Add("wid", WIDTextBox.Text.ToString());
    document.Add("name", NameComboBox.SelectedItem.ToString());

    foreach (SymboleCls item in SymbolesListBox.SelectedItems)
    {
        arrSym.Add(new BsonDocument("Name", item.Name));
    }
    document.Add("Symboles", arrSym);

    // needed only when replacing the Watchtbl
    //arrWatc.Add(document);

    // Do You really need to use async?
    collectionWatchtbl.UpdateOne(Builders<BsonDocument>.Filter.Eq("_id", UsersComboBox.SelectedItem), Builders<BsonDocument>.Update.AddToSet("Watchtbl", document));
}
```

And the POCO classes for deserialize>

```
public class UserWatchTblCls
{
    [BsonId]
    [BsonElement("_id")]
    public ObjectId Id { get; set; }

    public string fbId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [BsonElement("pass")]
    public string Pass { get; set; }

    [BsonElement("Watchtbl")]
    public List<WatchTblCls> WatchTbls { get; set; }
}

public class WatchTblCls
{
    [BsonElement("wid")]
    public string WID { get; set; }

    [BsonElement("name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [BsonElement("Symboles")]
    public List<SymboleCls> Symbols { get; set; }
}

public class SymboleCls
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: I don't understand this part, // in the UsersComboBox don't forget to set the DisplayMemberPath eqvivalent of Winforms to Name

Comment: I used WPF, so I set the `UsersComboBox.DisplayMemberPath` on the view to Name. You use winforms/telerik, so You need to set `UsersComboBox.DisplayMember` to Name.

Comment: set UsersComboBox.DisplayMember to Name??? §Name of what? the tools or what? and I don't use telerik here

Comment: @Juste3alfaz sorry `SymbolesListBox.DisplayMember = "Name"`. [https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listcontrol.displaymember(v=vs.110).aspx](here) You can see, that DisplayMember defines which property will be displayed in the list. So You can have `SymboleCls` objects as `ItemsSource`.